# How does Node.js module system handle modifying and accessing variable of the same module of different versions?

Tags: node.js

I have a custom Node.js module *fooModule* that has a private variable **foo** and public getter and setter to modify this variable.

I have another two modules: *zooModule* depends on the *fooModule@^1.0.1* and cannot use pre-release so far and *barModule* that depends on the *fooModule@^1.0.2-0* (pre-release patch version that contains some fix) and *zooModule* at the same time.

The *barModule* firstly sets the **foo** variable value and then *zooModule* reads the value of **foo**.

I have noticed that when the version of the *fooModule* dependency is the same, then it works as expected, in other words the **foo** variable is shared between two modules. However, using different versions results in *undefined* when accessing **foo** from *zooModule*.

Here is a small pseudo example to demonstrate the logic. Each of the modules is a standalone npm package.

```
// fooModule.js
let foo;
export const getFoo = () => foo;
export const setFoo = (newFoo) => foo = newFoo;

// zooModule.js uses v.1.0.1 of the fooModule
import { getFoo } from './fooModule.js'

export const zooFunc = () => {
    const zoo = getFoo();
    if(!zoo) return;
    ...
    return zoo; //result depends on zoo
};

// barModule.js uses v.1.0.2-0 of the fooModule
import { setFoo } from './fooModule.js'
import { zooFunc } from './zooModule.js'

setFoo('foo');
zooFunc(); // What is the output?
```

As far as I am concerned, in case of different versions of the fooModule, we become two different instances of the module and accordingly of the variable foo?

I tried to explain the question best I could, but it was hard to explain what I mean, sorry if it is still unclear. 
Could give me some hints where to read more about this or give some explanation on how this is supposed to work. Thanks for your time.

EDIT:I forgot to mention that I have this use case in a frontend project bundled by a webpack.

Comment: Yes, when different versions of the packages are used they are their own instances with different scopes and thus different values.